# WhatsApp Api para autenticación

Tags: whatsapp, sms

La idea es usar el WhatsApp para enviar un pequeño código al móvil, para prevenir el Spam y que los usuarios que se registren verifiquen su número de teléfono, algo súper simple.

Primero busqué el tema de los SMS, y lo que pedían era un abuso total, apenas ni 100 SMS y que si 50 Euros al mes, tampoco te aseguraban que llegasen, etc., todo para enviar un código de 4 o 6 dígitos, además de que esto es bajo demanda: no se sabe cuántos usuarios se van a registrar un día o bien otro, o quiénes van a cambiar de número o cuáles no.

Después encontré la posibilidad del WhatsApp Api, 2 días como quien dice para registrarse y enterarse de algo. La plantilla *hello_world* al final con la sintaxis que lleva y todo pues bien y se enviaba y se recibía, pero claro, no puedo trabajar con plantillas similares, dado que hay que generar un código para que llegue al usuario y antes hay que guardarlo.

He creado varias plantillas de tipo autenticación, seguí el esquema que indicaba, y todo el tiempo el error que le da a muchos sobre campos inexistentes, luego traté de ir a probar con templates creando un campo exclusivo y llevo 2 días esperando que alguien de Meta la revise, es tal cual.

Entonces si se puede añadir un texto personalizado agregado, ya me sirve porque ahí genero el código con PHP y ya está, pero no hay manera.

**Os pongo el código que he creado, la idea es agregar algo extra de contenido a la plantilla donde *1234* sería el código a enviar:**

```
$messageData = array(

'messaging_product' => "whatsapp",
'to' => "".$telefono."",
'type' => "template",
'template' => 
array(
"name"=> "otp_code",
'language'=>array("code"=>"es_ES"),
"components"=>array(array(
"type" => "body",
"parameters" => array(
        array("type"=>"text","text"=>"1234")
        )
))
)
);


$mensaje=json_encode($messageData);

$header = array("Authorization: Bearer " . $token, "Content-Type: application/json",);
//INICIAMOS EL CURL
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $mensaje);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//OBTENEMOS LA RESPUESTA DEL ENVIO DE INFORMACION
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
//IMPRIMIMOS LA RESPUESTA 
print_r($response);
//OBTENEMOS EL CODIGO DE LA RESPUESTA
$status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
//CERRAMOS EL CURL
curl_close($curl);
```

**Resultado :**

```
Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => (#100) The parameter messaging_product is required. [type]
```

No hay manera, y la información que hay es nula. ¿Cuál es la manera para hacer esto, para simplemente poder enviar un WhatsApp e incluir algo personalizado a pesar del template? Llevo probando días y no hay manera, y necesitaría una solución, porque he probado incluso Amazon Pinpoint y de todo y eso no hay manera de hacerlo funcionar tampoco, funciona el Amazon SNS pero es para campañas, y he programado con Lambda y siempre da "recurso no permitido" y todo tiene permisos, el resto nada.

Comment: No preguntes por "la mejor manera de..." porque las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Removí esa palabra para tratar de evitar esa situación. Por cierto, recuerda que [es.so] **no es un foro**.

Comment: Te fijaste algunas de las soluciones que figuran por SO??? yo para que no te planteen lo mismo...

Comment: Ya miré todo y en einglés, etc y nada de nada no consigo solucionar nada